# How to run a .cmd file through Jenkins?

Tags: shell, jenkins, cmd

I have a `.cmd` file that runs a simple script that I made. I want to run this through Jenkins however I am having trouble. As of the moment, under `execute shell` I have

`"%WORKSPACE%\FileMove\Runpse.cmd"`

This is simply the path to my file. This gives me the error,

`[workspace] $ sh -xe C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1.MOS\LOCALS~1\Temp\2\hudson1221785125766485285.sh
+ '%WORKSPACE%\ForgeFileMove\Runpse.cmd'
/cygdrive/c/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1.MOS/LOCALS~1/Temp/2/hudson1221785125766485285.sh: line 2: fg: no job control
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure`

I understand that the .sh files are just temporaries made by Jenkins, seeing as I cannot locate them on the computer. However I am unclear on what `fg: no job control` means. Do I have to do something other than just entering the path to my file under execute shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are running on windows, you should not `execute shell` but instead `Execute Windows batch command`